# spring 4 with quartz scheduler

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

**configuration**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="com.lokesh.tracker.integrations.jobs")
public class QuartzConfig {

    public JobDetailFactoryBean dailySummary(){
        JobDetailFactoryBean bean=new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        bean.setJobClass(DailySummary.class);
        bean.setName("dailySummary");
        bean.setGroup("dailySummaries");
        return bean;
    }


    public CronTriggerFactoryBean dailySummarytrigger(){
        CronTriggerFactoryBean bean=new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
        bean.setJobDetail(dailySummary().getObject());
        bean.setStartDelay(5000);
        bean.setBeanName("dailySummarytrigger");
        bean.setGroup("dailySummaries");
        bean.setCronExpression("0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *");
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean() {
        SchedulerFactoryBean scheduler = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        scheduler.setTriggers(dailySummarytrigger().getObject());
        return scheduler;
    } 
}
```

**Job**

```
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class DailySummary extends QuartzJobBean{

    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext arg0)
            throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }

}
```

**error**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'schedulerFactoryBean' defined in com.lokesh.tracker.config.QuartzConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.quartz.SchedulerException: Registration of jobs and triggers failed: null [See nested exception: java.lang.NullPointerException]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:736)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4992)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.quartz.SchedulerException: Registration of jobs and triggers failed: null [See nested exception: java.lang.NullPointerException]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerAccessor.registerJobsAndTriggers(SchedulerAccessor.java:254)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(SchedulerFactoryBean.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1633)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1570)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerAccessor.addTriggerToScheduler(SchedulerAccessor.java:291)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerAccessor.registerJobsAndTriggers(SchedulerAccessor.java:235)
    ... 24 more
```

Can some identify my errors. i am using Quartz for the first time. so i could not understand what it says in the error.In this example i want to execute daily summmary class with quartz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should annotate your `dailySummarytrigger` , `dailySummary` with `@Bean` annotation. These are full Spring beans and there is a post processing that happens before these beans are fully realized. You are bypassing these by not annotating them with `@Bean`

Answer (score 4):

You should use the @Scheduled annotation from spring instead of this configuration.

Check out this documentations: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling

All you need to do is to create a Scheduler bean and then annotate the method you like to run on a scheduled time with `@Scheduled(cron="0 0/1 * 1/1 * ? *")`